# Looking for Azure Pipeline YAML example for Maui iOS app

Tags: .net, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, maui

So far I have been unable to deploy my Maui app from Azure Devops.

Does anyone have a working example of a YAML file that I can look at?

The main issue at the moment is failure to sign the ipa file (yes I have a valid cert and provisioning file), but I also had issues with build which I had to workaround by using an older version of dotnet maui and the SDK.

I surely can't be the only person who has had trouble with this..?

Thanks

Comment: You should provide some code, maybe show your current YAML file and explain more thoroughly what you've tried and what errors you see

Comment: This is the (unhelpful)) error I get at the moment: ##[error]Error: The process '/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/bin/fastlane' failed with exit code 1. Looking at the ipa file on my mac tells me the file isn't signed.

Comment: @ewerspej - I have put my current YAML in an answer below

Comment: Please don't do that. Always update the question instead. Answers are for answers only. The same goes for comments, they're for commenting. Additonal information goes into the question, please.

Answer (score 0):

Here is [an YAML example](https://github.com/dotnet/maui-samples/blob/main/8.0/Apps/WeatherTwentyOne/devops/AzureDevOps/azdo_mac.yml) for building your Maui iOS app in Azure DevOps and you can refer to the session [DevOps with .NET MAUI using GitHub Actions & Azure DevOps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/events/dotnetconf-focus-on-maui/devops-with-dotnet-maui-using-github-actions-azure-devops) or the blog [Getting Started with DevOps and .NET MAUI](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/devops-for-dotnet-maui/) to learn more details.

Also you can refer to this doc [Setting up CI for your .NET MAUI iOS app in Azure DevOps](https://www.andreasnesheim.no/setting-up-ci-for-your-net-maui-ios-app-in-azure-devops/) and get the YAML example.

Answer (score 0):

Here is yaml of our running ios pipeline. I am using Flutter as build tool. I hope that helps.

```
name: $(Date:yyyyMMdd)$(Rev:r)
trigger:
  - develop

jobs:
  - job: IOS
    pool:
      vmImage: 'macOS-latest'
    steps:
    - task: FlutterInstall@0
      inputs:
        channel: 'stable'
        version: 'custom'
        customVersion: '3.0.5'
    - task: InstallAppleCertificate@2
      inputs:
        certSecureFile: 'MyApp_1.p12'
        certPwd: 'MyApp@123'
    - task: InstallAppleProvisioningProfile@1
      inputs:
        provisioningProfileLocation: 'secureFiles'
        provProfileSecureFile: 'MyApp_AppleStore_1.mobileprovision'

    - task: CmdLine@2
      inputs:
        script: '$(FlutterToolPath)/flutter clean' 
    - task: CmdLine@2
      inputs:
        script: '$(FlutterToolPath)/flutter pub get' 
    - task: CmdLine@2
      inputs:
        script: 'cd ios; pod deintegrate && pod cache clean --all; pod install' 
    - task: FlutterBuild@0
      inputs:
        target: 'ios'
        projectDirectory: '.'
        entryPoint: 'lib/main.dart'
        # splitPerAbi: true
        # extraArgs: '--obfuscate --split-debug-info=$(outputsSubDir)/$(debugSymbols)'

        # pod deintegrate && pod cache clean --all

    - task: Bash@3
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          xcodebuild -workspace ios/Runner.xcworkspace -scheme Runner -sdk iphoneos -configuration Release archive -archivePath build/ios/Runner.xcarchive
          xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath build/ios/Runner.xcarchive -exportOptionsPlist ios/exportOptions.plist -exportPath build/ios/App/
    - task: CopyFiles@2
      inputs:
        Contents: '**/*.ipa'
        TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      inputs:
        PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
        ArtifactName: 'drop'
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies - managed to work it out. The problems were largely caused by bugs with the latest versions of .net and maui when using .net 7. Had to put some workarounds in place.

Here is the working pipeline for future reference.

```
trigger:
  batch: true
  branches:
    include:
      - DEV

stages:


- stage: BuildiOS
  jobs:
  - job: BuildMAUIApps
    displayName: Build App
    pool:
      vmImage: 'macOS-12'
      demands:
      - MSBuild
      
    steps:
    
    - task: InstallAppleCertificate@2
      inputs:
        certSecureFile: 'AppStoreCert.p12'
        certPwd: '999999'
        keychain: 'temp'

    - task: InstallAppleProvisioningProfile@1
      inputs:
        provisioningProfileLocation: 'secureFiles'
        provProfileSecureFile: 'ProvisioningProfile.mobileprovision'

    - task: UseDotNet@2
      displayName: .NET Version
      inputs:
        packageType: 'sdk'
        version: '7.0.100'
    
    - task: CmdLine@2
      displayName: 'Install Maui'
      inputs:
        script: 'dotnet workload install maui --from-rollback-file https://maui.blob.core.windows.net/metadata/rollbacks/7.0.1xx.json --source https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/dnceng/public/_packaging/dotnet7/nuget/v3/index.json --source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json'

    - task: Bash@3
      displayName: Restore nuget
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          cd _Solutions/
          dotnet restore MyApp.sln

    - task: Bash@3
      displayName: Build iOS App
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          cd _Solutions/
          dotnet publish PMyApp.sln -f net7.0-ios -c Release

    - task: CopyFiles@2
      inputs:
        Contents: |
          **/*.app
          **/*.ipa
        TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'

    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      inputs:
        PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
        ArtifactName: 'drop_ios'
        publishLocation: 'Container'
```

Comment: Hi I have problem in building an ipa using Maui but works in xamarin.Does the above pipeline works? does it produce an ipa ? thanks

Comment: Hi @developer9969 yes this produces and ipa, but it is a very glitchy process to get it all setup. What problem are you having?

Comment: so is the pipeline successful? I am getting "code object is not signed at all" and this pipeline used to work and suddenly stopped with this error and the tasks for the Cert/provisioning profile is pretty standard , in the log it does say earlier "Detected signing identity" and its all correct but then later I get this "code object is not signed at all" so I am lost at what it could be as it used to work..

Comment: Yes the above pipeline works for me. I was also getting similar errors as you, but I think they are red herrings. I think the code not being signed is a side effect of something going wrong during build. This was one of the big problems I had because the error messages are not very good. I would start looking at the certs, provisioning, etc, to make sure that is all right. Something else I did was start with a new empty app and get it to deploy so at least I had something working, then gradually add in your other code. It took us months to work it out though.